# Is this proof of uniqueness of limit correct?

Tags: limits, analysis, solution-verification

I have to show that the limit of a function, if it exists, is unique.

My attempt is proceed by contradiction: so let's assume that $f(x)\to l_1$ as $x\to x_0$ and $f(x) \to l_2$ as $x \to x_0$, with $l_1 \ne l_2$.

By the first limit we have that for all $\varepsilon_1 >0$ there exists $\delta_1 >0$ such that $0<|x-x_0| < \delta_1$ implies $|f(x)-l_1| < \varepsilon_1$, by the second limit for all $\varepsilon_2 >0$ there exists $\delta_2 >0$ such that $0<|x-x_0| < \delta_2$ implies $|f(x)-l_2| < \varepsilon_2$.

Since $l_1 \ne l_2$ we can suppose, without loss of generality, that $l_1>l_2$ and since $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ are arbitrary we can choose $\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_2=\varepsilon$.

Let $\delta:=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, so if $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ we have that simultaneously
$$|f(x)-l_1|<\varepsilon \Leftrightarrow l_1-\varepsilon < f(x) < l_1+\varepsilon$$
$$|f(x)-l_2|<\varepsilon \Leftrightarrow l_2-\varepsilon < f(x) < l_2+\varepsilon$$
Since $l_1>l_2$, from the inequalities if follows that
$$l_1-\varepsilon<l_2+\varepsilon$$
Since $l_1>l_2$ it is $\frac{l_1-l_2}{2}>0$, so if we choose $\varepsilon<\frac{l_1-l_2}{2}$ we get
$$l_1-\varepsilon<l_2+\varepsilon\Rightarrow\varepsilon>l_1-\varepsilon-l_2=\frac{l_1-l_2}{2}$$
Which is a contradiction with $\varepsilon<\frac{l_1-l_2}{2}$, but I'm not sure if this is correct because in the last step I've substituted $\varepsilon$ only in one term and not in all the terms of the inequality.
Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: If you're starting with real analysis, I would strongly recommend you to try to prove this using the triangular inequality $|l_1 - l_2| \le |l_1 - f(x)| + |l_2 - f(x)| < 2\epsilon$. This should be easier, cleaner, and will give you the framework to prove half of the things following.

Comment: @volJunkie Thanks for your suggestion, I actually know how to prove it using the triangular inequality but somehow I feel more natural with this one I've posted, can I ask you if is correct and to check my final doubt? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't see any flaws except the last step should be $l_1 - l_2 - \epsilon > l_1 - l_2 - \frac{l_1 - l_2}2 = \frac{l_1 - l_2}2$.